# In opencv SGBM,why the left part of the disparity map become dark when I make the parameter named numDisparities larger?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

When use SGBM to get the disparity map,the left part of the pic get larger if I increase the parameter named numisparities. Is there any wrong with it?

[numisparities=6*16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEDze.png)

[numisparities=12*16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GuGM.png)

[numisparities=22*16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMKvo.png)

Related code :

```
num = cv2.getTrackbarPos("num", "depth")
blockSize = cv2.getTrackbarPos("blockSize", "depth")
window_size = cv2.getTrackbarPos("windowSize","depth")
if blockSize % 2 == 0:
    blockSize += 1
if blockSize < 5:
    blockSize = 5


min_disp = 0
num_disp = 16 * num - min_disp
stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(minDisparity=min_disp,
                               numDisparities=num_disp,
                               blockSize=blockSize,
                               P1=8 * 3 * window_size ** 2,
                               P2=32 * 3 * window_size ** 2,
                               disp12MaxDiff=1,
                               uniquenessRatio=10,
                               speckleWindowSize=100,
                               speckleRange=32
                               )
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR).astype(np.float32) / 16.0
disp = cv2.normalize(disparity, disparity, alpha=0, beta=255, 
norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the search range. The stereo matching is done using the no of disparities. In other words, Pixel A in left image is searched in right image with a numdisparity parameter only. For searching from left w.r.to right, the left part is discarded.

To get this area filled, usually they do both left w.r.to right disparity and right w.r.to left disparity and do LR consistency check.

Comment: Sorry，I still can not understand why the left part should be discarded.For a rectified pair , the  pixel of left image locating in x will  search from x to x+numdisparity in the right image?If this is right,why the left part is discarded?